# How to submit a POST request using data from webpage with curl & grep (or any busybox alternative)

Tags: linux, curl, terminal, grep

Question:

I have a webpage on the server like this:

```
...
<form action="/" action="POST">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="4Tredir" value="/" />
    <input type="hidden" name="magic" value="(some hex number here)" />
    ...
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
</form>
...
```

Is it possible by using command provided by busybox (i.e. `curl`, `grep`, etc.) to submit a post to a known address (e.g. `http://exampleauth.com/`) with my own username, password and the `magic` value in the webpage?

*Additional information:* the HTML is written all in one line without line break, and the format of magic number is fixed. i.e. `[0-9a-f]{16}`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this below on a SElinux with curl 7.19.7

```
    curl exampleauth.com | grep -ioE "[0-9a-f]{16}" | curl -F "username=abc" -F "password=123" -F magic=\<- exampleauth.com
```

step by step:

1. get the html with form

   ```
   curl exampleauth.com
   ```
2. find the magic with regular exp. You might need to adjust it

   ```
   grep -ioE "[0-9a-f]{16}"
   ```
3. send the data as if form submitted. Note the "<-" meaning "use STDIN"

   ```
   curl -F "username=abc" -F "password=123" -F magic=\<- exampleauth.com
   ```

Found these helpful:
[Extract a pattern from the output of curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707129/extract-a-pattern-from-the-output-of-curl)
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use /bin/echo and /usr/bin/nc

```
[prompt] BODY='{"4Tredir":"","magic":"[0-9a-f]{16}","username":"johndoe",  "password":"mypassword"}'
[prompt] LEN=$(busybox echo -n ${BODY} | wc -c)
[prompt] echo -ne "POST /form.html HTTP/1.0\r\nHost:www.exampleauth.com\r\n\Accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: ${LEN}\r\n\r\n$BODY" | nc -i 3 www.exampleauth.com 8080
```